# Triggering an alarm on MBP while the lid is closed

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, sleep-wake, alarm

I would like to use an alarm clock application on my MacBook Pro. The thing is, that I need to close the lid on the MBP while sleeping. Now I know this is a common issue, but after moderate amount of Googling I haven't found any reasonable solution. Some solutions are already old, do not work on 10.6.7 or the current line of MBP.

[This application](http://www.robbiehanson.com/alarmclock/index.html) almost works. It has everything alarm clock should have. It can wakes the computer from sleep as well. It has some problems with closed lid though. The alarm fires of, but after like 3 seconds it auto snoozes. After snooze cool down expires the same thing happens again. If the lid is open and MBP is sleeping the application works just fine.

Can anyone recommend any other application?

ps. Now I know, that running MBP closed is not recommended due to possible overheating, but all need it the alarm clock, so after 10-20 seconds I will manually turn it off, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Actually operating the MacBook with closed lid ("closed clamshell mode") is not a problem and supported by Apple: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3131

Comment: You didn't mention why you need to keep the lid closed. Anything that could be solved in another question? Did InsomniaX or InsomniaT work?

Answer (score 1):

I used to use InsomniaX, but it has stopped working with the recent updates, and the developer's site says he's stop development. However, I found a similar app that works called InsomniaT. It's not quite as useful as InsomniaX, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to close the lid because the screen display is keeping you awake, can I suggest ctrl-shift-eject as a quick shortcut to turn off the display, whilst leaving the machine running as normal?  I use it all the time in the scenario you are describing.

Answer (score -1):

There are two actions at play here, and if you'd to consider as two separate actions, you'd be able to explain what you've observed.

1. Sleep. Sleep can be triggered in several ways. Inactivity (under Energy Saver), explicit (by you via keyboard or GUI) and lid close.
2. Lid Close. Will usually trigger a sleep, but it need not be.

All the alarm apps mentioned on this page is unaware of "lid close". So the following infinite loop occurs:
Alarm triggers -> wake from sleep -> detect lid closed -> sleep -> alarm triggers -> wake from sleep -> detect lid close -> sleep -> ....

The answer to this question lies in taking a step back and trying to understand what you're trying to achieve, and solve it using a different line of thought.